# Probability distributions in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to solve a constrained NLP in Pyomo. However, the objective function includes a normal distribution where the argument of the normal distribution contains the decision variable, e.g. an expression like - `(norm.cdf(model.x[0]))`.

But I receive this error:

```
 Cannot convert object of type 'ndarray' (value = 1) to a numeric value.
```

Is there a way of working with normal distributions in Pyomo?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't use the variable as parameter, because pyomo's variable isn't the python's variable. You could write the expression of the normal distribution, maybe this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that pyomo isn't a fan of some of the typical math you might be used to wanting in pyton or black box functions ([Optimizing Fortran function in pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176181/optimizing-fortran-function-in-pyomo) and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/dK71XrHlBIM).

I think in this case you probably will need to write out an approximation of the normal cdf in the object (gross, I know). Might I suggest:

```
1/(model.x[0]*2.50663)*(1-model.x[0]**-2+3*model.x[0]**-4+15*model.x[0]**-6-105*model.x[0]**-8)
```

which is based on this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19404/approximation-of-a-normal-distribution-function

Here is a cool paper of other options: http://www.hrpub.org/download/20140305/MS7-13401470.pdf