# No value for uninitialized NumericValue object - Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm working on an optimization model in python with the pyomo library (I just started using this). I can model in excel with the necessary constraints. However I'm getting an error message in python that I cannot seem to understand. The code and error message is below.
All help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
from scipy.stats import norm

setup_cost = 125
holding_cost = 17
annual_demand = 1200
std_annual_demand = 70
lead_time = 1/52


ltd = annual_demand*lead_time
std_ltd = 9.707

model = ConcreteModel()
model.order_quantity = Var(bounds = (0,None))
model.multiple_k = Var(bounds = (0,None))

def total_annual_cost(model):
    orders_per_year = annual_demand/model.order_quantity
    safety_stock = model.multiple_k * std_ltd

    annual_ordering_cost = orders_per_year * setup_cost
    annual_holding_cost = holding_cost*(safety_stock+model.order_quantity/2)
    total_cost = annual_holding_cost + annual_ordering_cost


    return total_cost

def service_level(model):
    k = value(model.multiple_k)
    order_quantity = value(model.order_quantity)
    #expected_shortage_per_cycle = (norm.pdf(model.multiple_k)-model.multiple_k*(1-norm.cdf(model.multiple_k))) * std_ltd
    expected_shortage_per_cycle = (norm.pdf(k)- k *(1-norm.cdf(k))) * std_ltd
    service_level = 1-expected_shortage_per_cycle/order_quantity
    return service_level 

#model.service_level = Expression(initialize = ((norm.pdf(model.multiple_k)-model.multiple_k*(1-norm.cdf(model.multiple_k))) * std_ltd))

model.service_level_constraint = Constraint(rule = service_level)
model.objective = Objective(rule = total_annual_cost, sense = 1)


solver = SolverFactory('ipopt') 
status = solver.solve(model)
```

ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: multiple_k
        (object: )
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object multiple_k

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint
    service_level_constraint: ValueError: No value for uninitialized
    NumericValue object multiple_k

ERROR: Constructing component 'service_level_constraint' from data=None
    failed: ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
    multiple_k

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit. However, I feel like your edited question is a completely different problem. It is better to make a new question when that happens, or maybe, keep the old question and add what you have tried as an update to the original question. That being said, before you or a moderator edit the question to the original problem, I can help you with what you tried. In fact, you can't just do what you did, it won't work no matter what you do. One of Pyomo's job is to write a static model file from Python code. In the solver, it is a static mathematical problem with static equations...

Comment: ... The solver can't run Python code in itself, it runs equations, so each constraint rule function must not compute things with variable values, but only and simply write an equation to provide the solver with it. Everything arround the decision variable MUST be computed only by equations. No Pyton function (`norm.pdf`, `norm.cdf`), no python instructions, only instructions to write the equations that will take this kind of decisions. If you do take that in consideration, it will be easier to model any problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm getting closer to figuring it out with your help

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but you are using functions (`norm.pdf` and `norm.cdf`) that can't be used with model variables in a mathematical programming model.

If you are to use such function, you have to use them on parameters only. And if you want to use them with model variables as an argument, it might be interesting to rewrite them directly in your model. While it is easy to do so for `norm.pdf`, it might be harder with `norm.cdf` as the formula to compute it is indefinite.

See the question at [Probability distributions in pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037358/probability-distributions-in-pyomo) for a discussion on how to use or adapt `norm.cdf` into an optimization model. I also posted a more general question on the OR StackExchange site [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/standard-cumulative-distribution-function-with-optimization-model-variable) because this is a mathematical formulation common to all AMLs.

Comment: Thanks. I think I notice the first part of the problem. I will post an updated code with different error message.

Comment: @kwespiipi Someone answered the question I posted in the second link I provided you. Feel free to look at it since it gives a clever way of rewritting a constraint when such black boxes are included in the constraint rule. BTW, don't forget to add a `<=`, a `>=` or a `==` in your constraint rule expression, otherwise it is not a constraint but merely an expression.

Comment: Following the links you provided was very helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you succeeded to solve your problem, feel free to answer your own question with a concrete example and mark it as the answer, so it can help other users who faces the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of @V. Brunelle, I rewrote the pdf and cdf functions directly into the constraint and it worked like magic.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

setup_cost = 125
holding_cost = 17 
annual_demand = 1200
std_annual_demand = 70
lead_time = 1/52



ltd = annual_demand*lead_time
std_ltd = 9.707

model = ConcreteModel()

model.order_quantity = Var(bounds = (0,None))
model.multiple_k = Var(bounds = (0,None))

def total_annual_cost(model):


    safety_stock = model.multiple_k * std_ltd
    orders_per_year = annual_demand/model.order_quantity

    annual_ordering_cost = orders_per_year * setup_cost
    annual_holding_cost = holding_cost*(safety_stock+(model.order_quantity/2))


    total_cost = annual_holding_cost + annual_ordering_cost 

    return total_cost


def service_level_req(model):
    e = np.exp(1)
    pi = np.pi
    pdf = e**(-((model.multiple_k ** 2)/2))/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
    cdf = 1/(1+ (e**(-(model.multiple_k * 1.65451))))

    expected_shortage_per_cycle = (pdf - ((1-cdf)*model.multiple_k))* std_ltd
    service_level = 1-expected_shortage_per_cycle/model.order_quantity

    return service_level >= .98

def turn_requirement(model):
    rop = model.multiple_k * std_ltd + ltd
    max_rop = model.order_quantity-1 + rop
    turn = annual_demand/max_rop
    return turn >= 6

model.sl_const = Constraint(rule = service_level_req)
model.turn_const = Constraint(rule = turn_requirement)
model.objective = Objective(rule = total_annual_cost, sense = 1)


solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
status = solver.solve(model)
```